# Coinase API issue

Tags: android, coinbase-api

I am trying to use Coinbase api. However there is no luch.
Here is my code of the function:

```
public void sendPaymnet(String accountEmail){
    Coinbase cb = new CoinbaseBuilder()
            .withApiKey(System.getenv("xxxxxxx"), System.getenv("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"))
            .build();
    Transaction t = new Transaction();
    t.setTo(accountEmail);
    t.setAmount(Money.parse("USD 0.01"));
    Transaction r = cb.sendMoney(t);

}
```

It's showing error on the line : cb.sendMoney(t); and when I try to run the code the app stops. Thanks in advance

Comment: fell free to tell us the error to help you. What exactly is the error?